# how to process a form in html without using any button?

Tags: forms, input

Can anyone please tell me how to insert data into database without page refresh and without using any button. Facebook wall posts area is an example. User writes whatever he wants in input field and he has to press ENTER to submit the data into database instead of using a submit button.

Comment: Using java script timer and Ajax you can do it. When timer will run it will automatically save your data to database.

Comment: @nareshkumar any example? I don't think i need to use timer. All i want is, whenever a user gives any input, all he has to do is to Press Enter button from keyboard and data should be inserted into database.

Comment: ok, then you have to work with the keyboard event. inside a if condition you have to check that if, user pressed the enter key, then you have to process the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery, you can do something along the lines of:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        your submit code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers automatically submit a form if you hit enter within a `<input type="text">` element.

Try

```
<form action="" onsubmit="alert(document.getElementById('t').value); return false;">
  <input type="text" id="t">
</form>
```